# rails nested resource: Move from child/show.html to parent/show.html using link_to or other Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, nested-resources

I have a phones resource nested within a user one, and each have independent views. I can use link_to to get to the nested resource, phones, but am unable to go back in the opposite direction and link back to user views from within a phone view.

I have tried nearly every command I could find on google, such as link_to, url_for, polymorphic_url, all without success.

Thanks

Wex

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with how your routes are setup. Go to project directory and type "rake routes", this will give you a list of all available routes. If this doesn't put you on the right path, post the output of rake routes, the controller, and the view code.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I have posted the rake routes results as you requested.

Comment: @W.Wuffley The `rake routes` results should have been posted to the question, not to Jay's answer.  Please edit the question and include this information there.